# What's a good strategy for clean/reliable shutdown of threads that use pthread barriers for synchronization?

Tags: c, pthreads, pthread-barriers

I've got a pthread-based multithreaded program that has four threads indefinitely executing this run-loop (pseudocode):

```
while(keepRunning)
{
   pthread_barrier_wait(&g_stage_one_barrier);

   UpdateThisThreadsStateVariables();  

   pthread_barrier_wait(&g_stage_two_barrier);

   DoComputationsThatReadFromAllThreadsStateVariables();
}
```

This works pretty well, in that during stage one each thread updates its own state variables, and that's okay because no other thread is reading any other thread's state variables during stage one.  Then during stage two it's a free-for-all as far as threads reading each others' state is concerned, but that's okay because during stage two no thread is modifying its local state variables, so they are effectively read-only.

My only remaining problem is, how do I cleanly and reliably shut down these threads when it's time for my application to quit?  (By "cleanly and reliably", I mean without introducing potential deadlocks or race conditions, and ideally without having to send any UNIX-signals to force threads out of a pthread_barrier_wait() call)

My main() thread can of course set keepRunning to false for each thread, but then how does it get pthread_barrier_wait() to return for each thread?  AFAICT the only way to get pthread_barrier_wait() to return is to have all four threads' execution-location inside pthread_barrier_wait() simultaneously, but that's difficult to do when some threads may have exited already.

Calling pthread_barrier_destroy() seems like what I'd want to do, but it's undefined behavior to do that while any threads might be waiting on the barrier.

Is there a good known solution to this problem?

Comment: What is the two 'wait' events that every thread is waiting for on each loop?  Perhaps have the main() function simply reset the 'keeprunning' variable and repeatedly trigger each of the 'wait' events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having two flags and using something like the following should work:

```
for (;;)
{
    pthread_barrier_wait(&g_stage_one_barrier);           +
                                                          |
    UpdateThisThreadsStateVariables();                    |
                                                          |
    pthread_mutex_lock(&shutdownMtx);                     | Zone 1
    pendingShutdown = !keepRunning;                       |
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&shutdownMtx);                   |
                                                          |
    pthread_barrier_wait(&g_stage_two_barrier);           +
                                                          |
    if (pendingShutdown)                                  |
        break;                                            | Zone 2
                                                          |
    DoComputationsThatReadFromAllThreadsStateVariables(); |
}
```

`shutdownMtx` should protect the setting of `keepRunning` too, though it's not shown.

The logic is that by the time `pendingShutdown` gets set to `true`, all the threads must be within *Zone 1*. (This is true even if only some of the threads saw `keepRunning` being `false`, so races on `keepRunning` should be okay.) It follows that they will all reach `pthread_barrier_wait(&g_stage_two_barrier)`, and then all break out when they enter *Zone 2*.

It would also be possible to check for `PTHREAD_BARRIER_SERIAL_THREAD` -- which is returned by `pthread_barrier_wait()` for exactly one of the threads -- and only do the locking and updating of `pendingShutdown` in that thread, which could improve performance.

Comment: Racing condition: different threads may get different values from `keepRunning` at the same iteration.

Comment: Ah, I was assuming `keepRunning` was a global "shut down process" flag. Perhaps that was a misunderstanding. If `pendingShutdown` and `keepRunning` are globals it shouldn't matter if different threads see different values, since the invariant that all threads must be in *Zone 1* if *some* thread sets `pendingShutdown` to `true` should hold. (`keepRunning` and `pendingShutdown` might need to be protected by mutexes too.)

Comment: Yes, there is a race with global variable. There is no guarantee the value is changed when there are  no threads splitted before and after the test. The approach mandates that all the threads are either before or after the test, which is not achieved here.

Comment: Hmm... could you give a concrete example of when this might break?

Comment: 2 threads: one has already reached stage 2 and second one is doing first update. You change the flag, the second thread picks up exit value, enters the second barrier, both threadx leave it. Second thread exits and the first one block in the first barrier, as it has missed the flag update.

Comment: What do you mean by "has already reached stage 2"? That it's waiting in `pthread_barrier_wait(&g_stage_two_barrier)`? In that case, shouldn't it wait there until the second thread gets there too, and then pick up that `pendingShutdown` is true once it leaves the barrier?

Comment: Declaring `pendingShutdown` and `keepRunning` as `volatile` and adding simple critical section around `pendingShutdown != keepRunning` resolves all possible race conditions.

Comment: @Ulfalizer: Looks fine to me.  The main advantage of doing it in just one thread is that otherwise the `shutdownMtx` will bounce between CPU caches.

Comment: @Ulfalizer: I've delete my comments that no longer apply to this version, I suggest you do the same.

Answer (score 2):

You could have an additional thread that synchronises on the same barriers, but only exists as a "shutdown master".  Your worker threads would use the exact code that you have in your question, and the "shutdown master" thread would do:

```
while (keepRunning)
{
    pthread_barrier_wait(&g_stage_one_barrier);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mkr_lock);
    if (!mainKeepRunning)
        keepRunning = 0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mkr_lock);

    pthread_barrier_wait(&g_stage_two_barrier);
}
```

When the main thread wants the other threads to shut down, it would just do:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mkr_lock);
mainKeepRunning = 0;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mkr_lock);
```

(ie. the `keepRunning` variable becomes part of the shared thread state that is read-only during stage 2, and is owned by the shutdown master thread during stage 1).

Of course, you can also just pick one of your other threads to be the "shutdown master thread" rather than using a dedicated thread for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

There is a conflict of requirements: barrier semantics require all threads to be `in` to continue, and shutdown requires termination when threads are shared between execution blocks (could be inside different barriers).

I suggest to replace barrier with a custom implementation that would support extern `cancel` call.

Example (may not run, but the idea...):

```
struct _barrier_entry
{
  pthread_cond_t cond;
  volatile bool released;
  volatile struct _barrier_entry *next;
};

typedef struct
{
  volatile int capacity;
  volatile int count;
  volatile struct _barrier_entry *first;
  pthread_mutex_t lock;
} custom_barrier_t;
```

Initialization:

```
int custom_barrier_init(custom_barrier_t *barrier, int capacity)
{
   if (NULL == barrier || capacity <= 0)
   {
     errno = EINVAL;
     return -1;
   }
   barrier->capacity = capacity;
   barrier->count = 0;
   barrier->first = NULL;
   return pthread_mutex_init(&barrier->lock, NULL);
   return -1;
}
```

Helper:

```
static void _custom_barrier_flush(custom_barrier_t *barrier)
{
   struct _barrier_entry *ptr;
   for (ptr = barrier->first; NULL != ptr;)
   {
     struct _barrier_entry *next = ptr->next;
     ptr->released = true;
     pthread_cond_signal(&ptr->cond);
     ptr = next;
   }
   barrier->first = NULL;
   barrier->count = 0;
}
```

Blocking wait:

```
int custom_barrier_wait(custom_barrier_t *barrier)
{
   struct _barrier_entry entry;
   int result;
   pthread_cond_init(&barrier->entry, NULL);
   entry->next = NULL;
   entry->released = false;

   pthread_mutex_lock(&barrier->lock);
   barrier->count++;
   if (barrier->count == barrier->capacity)
   {
     _custom_barrier_flush(barrier);
     result = 0;
   }
   else
   {
     entry->next = barrier->first;
     barrier->first = entry;
     while (true)
     {
       pthread_cond_wait(&entry->cond, &barrier->lock);
       if (entry->released)
       {
         result = 0;
         break;
       }
       if (barrier->capacity < 0)
       {
         errno = ECANCELLED;
         result = -1;
         break;
       }
     }
   }
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&barrier->lock);
   pthread_cond_destroy(&entry->cond);
   return result;
}
```

Cancellation:

```
 int custom_barrier_cancel(custom_barrier_t *barrier)
 {
   pthread_mutex_lock(barrier->lock);
   barrier->capacity = -1;
   _custom_barrier_flush(barrier);
   pthread_mutex_unlock(barrier->lock);
   return 0;
 }
```

So the thread code can run in the loop, until it gets `ECANCELLED` error after `custom_barrier_wait` call.

Answer (score 0):

The threads that are waiting at the barriers are not the issue, it's the threads that are still running `UpdateThis...` or `DoComputations...` that will delay the shutdown. You can reduce the shutdown time by periodically checking for shutdown inside the `UpdateThis...` and `DoComputations...` functions.

Here's the outline of one possible solution

- main initializes a mutex `g_shutdown_mutex`
- main locks the mutex
- main launches the threads
- the threads do their thing while periodically trying to lock the
  mutex, but since main has the mutex locked, the `trylock` function
  will always fail
- when it's time to shutdown, main unlocks the mutex
- now the `trylock` will succeed and the worker functions will return early
- before reaching the second barrier, any thread that successfully locks the mutex sets a global variable `g_shutdown_requested`
- after passing the second barrier, all the threads will see the same value in `g_shutdown_requested` and make the same decision whether to exit or not

---

So the `while` loop looks like this

```
while(1)
{
    pthread_barrier_wait(&g_stage_one_barrier);

    UpdateThisThreadsStateVariables();

    if ( pthread_mutex_trylock( &g_shutdown_mutex ) == 0 )
    {
        g_shutdown_requested = true;
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &g_shutdown_mutex );
        break;
    }

    pthread_barrier_wait(&g_stage_two_barrier);

    if ( g_shutdown_requested )
        break;

    DoComputationsThatReadFromAllThreadsStateVariables();
}
```

And the worker functions look like this

```
void UpdateThisThreadsStateVariables( void )
{
    for ( i = 0;; i++ )
    {
        // check the mutex once every 4000 times through the loop
        if ( (i & 0xfff) == 0 && pthread_mutex_trylock( &g_shutdown_mutex ) == 0 )
        {
            pthread_mutex_unlock( &g_shutdown_mutex );   // abnormal termination
            return; 
        }

        // do the important stuff here

        if ( doneWithTheImportantStuff )    // normal termination
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code would deadlock when `main` unlocks mutex after one of the thread manages to pass locking test, but others do not.

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk Any thread that passes the locking test immediately unlocks the mutex, so no, there is no deadlock. Perhaps that was not clear in the outline, but it should be clear from the code. The `mutex` is just a signal to the threads that they should shutdown (instead of the `keepRunning` variable). None of the threads will keep the mutex locked.

Comment: Still, if there are 4 total threads, 3 threads have failed to lock the mutex and continued, and one locks it, then 3 would end in indefinite wait inside first barrier block, and one would exit.

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk Yes, I see now thanks! After the threads pass the second barrier, they must all make the same decision to either continue or exit. My code didn't guarantee that. I'll update the code.